Neovim LSP client is not responding with 'initialized' method notification
I'm trying to build a language server from scratch just for learning how it works, so far I've got the initialize method request and I've responded with empty capabilities and server info, but I'm not getting any further requests from neovim, (using STDIO)
import rpc
import sys
import logging
import json


logging.basicConfig(filename='server.log',
                    level=logging.DEBUG,
                    filemode='w',
                    format='%(asctime)s %(levelname)s - %(message)s')

logging.info('Server logging initiated')
while True:
    header = ''
    while True:
        line = sys.stdin.readline().strip()
        if not line:
            break
        header = line

    bytes_to_read = int(header[len('Content-Length: '):])
    content = sys.stdin.read(bytes_to_read)
    request = json.loads(content)
    client_name = request['params']['clientInfo']['name']
    client_version = request['params']['clientInfo']['version']
    logging.info(f'Connected to client: {client_name} {client_version}')
    logging.info(f'Received method: {request['method']}')
    response = {
        'jsonrpc': '2.0',
        'id': request['id'],
        'result': {
            'serverInfo': {
                'name': 'my-ls',
                'version': '0.1.0'
            },
            'capabilities': {}
        }
    }

    sys.stdout.write(f'Content-Length: {len(json.dumps(response))}\r\n\r\n')
    sys.stdout.write(json.dumps(response))
    sys.stdout.flush()
    logging.info(f'Sent response')

here's the log that I get:
2024-06-03 21:10:01,296 INFO - Server logging initiated
2024-06-03 21:10:01,296 INFO - Connected to client: Neovim 0.9.4
2024-06-03 21:10:01,296 INFO - Received method: initialize
2024-06-03 21:10:01,296 INFO - Sent response

what I expect to get is the initialized method notification and further messages, once I sent the response for the initialize method I get nothing. I checked neovims lsp.log and it only shows the request that was sent.

I believe the issue with the content length - you're assigning the length of the response json and ignoring the "\r\n\r\n" - which are 4 additional bytes to send. Maybe smth like:
sys.stdout.write(f'Content-Length: {len(json.dumps(response)) + 4}\r\n\r\n')
UPDATE
Nvmd - just checked it, the content length should not include the "\r\n\r\n" part.
